# How to show/hide a span using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone show a way to show/hide a span using javascript

```
 document.getElementById("test").style.display= 'visible';
 document.getElementById("test").style.display= 'block';
```

In the HTML Code

```
<span id='test' ..
```

How can I overcome this problem. Is there any thing that I should think about?

**UPDATE**
I have a class like this one, I want to force mouse hovering on it.

```
<div id="test" class="tooltip effect">
        <div id="second" href="#"> .. </div>
```

On css:

```
tooltip{..}
effect{..}
effect:hover{..}
```

Another option I tried besides your code is

```
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = test.hover;
```

- Should I re-write the hover class to another name-class, or should I tweak your code?

Comment: Are you sure you want `display:block` to be applied to `span`? `display:inline` seems to be a better choice. Actually, some libraries implement their `hide()/show()` methods with caching the existing value of `style.display`...

Comment: Can you give more details, plz. This is what I wanna do.

Answer (score 10):

Use display none/default:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display= 'none';
document.getElementById("test").style.display= '';
```

Below are some types and some easy to remember rules about them:

Default: the elements default property (generally block or inline)

Block: Generally on a line by itself. Has the width and height attributes (among other size/positioning attributes)

inline: on the same line as other elements/text. Does not have height/width attributes

Inherit: Inherits the parent element's display type

Answer (score 1):

`visible` isn't a value for the display, you want `none`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to handle it:

```
function HideAndSeek(selector) {

    var elements = undefined;
    var displays = [];

    if (!!selector.id) {
        elements = [document.getElementById(selector.id)];
    } else if (!!selector.class) {
        elements = document.getElementsByClass(selector.class);
    }

    for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elements.length; elementIndex++) {
        displays[elementIndex] = elements[elementIndex].style.display;
    }

    this.hide = function() {
        for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elements.length; elementIndex++) {
            elements[elementIndex].style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    this.show = function() {
        for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elements.length; elementIndex++) {
            elements[elementIndex].style.display = displays[elementIndex];
        }
    };
}
```

This function can be used this way:

```
var hideAndSeek = new HideAndSeek({id: "test"});
```

and you can hide the element(s) by:

```
hideAndSeek.hide();
```

you can show them by:

```
hideAndSeek.show();
```

Comment: @user3378649, I have tested the code and it works impeccably for me. Please tell me how did you try to use it, what did you expect, what happened instead and what error message did you receive (if any) in which browser in what HTML. Thanks.

Comment: My code solves the problem of hiding showing HTML tags having an id or similar class, solving the problem asked in your question. Your update deals with a totally different problem. So I am confused, as I do not really understand what you want to do. If it is hiding/showing things in Javascript, then my code should solve the problem. If force hovering, then it is a different issue. Hover is a UI event and if you do not want to do anything extreme, then you can add/remove a class. If you want to do something extreme, you can implement a separate function and call it whenever you want hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="text-danger" id="spanAddressLine1" runat="server" style="display: none;"> //Here is your message </span>
```

JQuery code

For show:
$('#<%= spanAddressLine1.ClientID%>').show();

For hide:
$('#<%= spanAddressLine1.ClientID%>').hide();

Here spanAddressLine1 is the id of span